# JBoss wildfly 10 forbidden access for spring mvc web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, wildfly

I have a spring mvc application running into JBoss 4.2. I'm trying migrate this web app to **JBoss wildfly 10** (wildfly-10.0.0.Final version). The app deploy successfully but when I try to access http://localhost:8080/myApp/ the server retuns **"Forbidden"**. And if I try to access to http://localhost:8080/myApp/web/buscador/init server response "Not Found".

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- char encoding -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/myAppApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- servlet dispatcher de Spring -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/myAppApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- DWR -->
    <servlet>
        <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- displaytag -->
    <servlet>
        <display-name>DisplaySource</display-name>
        <servlet-name>DisplaySource</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.displaytag.sample.DisplaySourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DisplaySource</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.source</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://displaytag.sourceforge.net</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/displaytag.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

And this is a request mapping:

```
    @RequestMapping("/buscador/init")
public String initForm(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {        

    //anadimos los datos de la gestion de incidencias al modelo
    model.addAttribute(Constantes.ATTRIBUTE_OFICINA_CTA, oficinaCTA);

    return Views.VIEW_BUSCADOR_OFICINA;
}
```

I think that issue is due for spring-mvn request mapping because with another frameworks work fine.

The logs when deploy the app:

```
2016-08-19 08:23:22,611 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "myApp.war" (runtime-name: "myApp.war")
2016-08-19 08:23:27,178 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /myApp
2016-08-19 08:23:27,365 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "myApp.war" (runtime-name : "myApp.war")
```

Comment: Which version of wildfly 10 are you using ? If possible, use the latest version from here http://wildfly.org/downloads/

Comment: I use wildfly-10.0.0.Final version. I try in wildfly-9.0.2.Final and obtain same issue. Thanks @SkyWalker

Comment: Are you deploying it as myApp.war? Do you have a jboss-web.xml?

Comment: Also, start the server without your application. Once it finishes starting, do the deployment and paste the log entries for the deployment on this question. Chances are that the context onto which it was deployed is shown on the logs.

Comment: @jpkrohling I'm deploying it as myApp.war. I don't have  jboss-web.xml. I have added the logs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the war was corrupted